# NuGet: Do Not Set Assembly Reference

Tags: nuget

I have created a nuget package containing a DLL that I want to share with multiple applications.  I want to add this package to applications without setting a reference to the DLL.  I am using dependency injection to load this DLL or a test DLL at run-time.

By default, nuget automatically sets a reference to all DLLs contained lib during installation.

Is there any way to configure the nuget package to not set a reference to the DLL when it is installed into my project?

Answer (score 1):

[Explicit assembly references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/nuspec#explicit-assembly-references). Although if your dll is loaded entirely at runtime (using MEF or `Assembly.Load` or something similar), then the build system might not copy the dll to the project's output directory. Note these docs are only correct for `packages.config` projects. I have a [PR](https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/pull/1443) to improve the docs to explain how to do the equivalent thing for `PackageReference`.

Comment: But this describes how to explicitly add a reference where one does not exist.  My problem is that nuget is adding a reference where I do not want one.   There does not seem to be a "don't reference" flag for the main assembly.

Comment: when the nuspec doesn't have any `<references>` element, NuGet will add references to every dll in the package (for the selected TFM). By using `<references>`, it tells NuGet which dlls to add references to in the project's csproj, and any dll you don't list in the nuspec `<references>` section will not get added to the csproj.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "explicitly add a reference where one does not exist". What do you beleive the docs are explaining?

Comment: I know what the documentation says, zivkan.  It does not work that way.  Even when you define the <references> element with nothing in it, nuget still sets a reference to the main DLL.

Comment: Try it yourself.

Comment: My package contains one DLL that I DO NOT want the project to reference. What should I put between <references>?  Nothing?  It still reference the DLL.  Sorry,  I'm not sure how much clearer I can be.

Comment: I didn't get that your package contained only 1 dll before. You could try using the `<group>` element with whatever target framework you use, to see if that allows you to specify no references. But I don't think this will work for packages.config projects because of how ResolveAssemblyReference works (see my docs PR for links and a brief description). I think it might work for ProjectReference projects if you create an empty `ref\<tfm>\_._` file

Comment: Interestingly, when I add `<group>`, `<reference>` elements are _required_.

Comment: Evidently PackageReference is not supported for ASP.net projects yet. :-(

Comment: PR has some [package compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#package-compatibility-issues) differences. For ASP.NET it's most often about getting css or js from the package. But if you don't use that, then you can use PR in ASP.NET. You need to uninstall all packages, ensure that the visual studio nuget options asks you which format on first package install, then install your packages again.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the PackageReference format is supported by the Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Comment: PackageReference was added before I joined the team, but I think it was around NuGet 4.2 or 4.3. As long as you use a NuGet version greater than this, yes. Unsurprisingly I recommend using the latest version of NuGet.